# Handling private fields in Scala traits when implementing them in Java

Tags: java, scala, interop, traits

When implementing a Scala trait, one has to implement the trait's methods and the simply call the respective static method on `Foo$class.class`. I'm not sure however how to deal with private fields which are defined in the trait.

That is, if there is a field `_something` in the trait, if I don't implement `_something_$eq()` and `_something()`, the compiler yells at me. My assumption is that I have to create a `_something` field in my implementing class.

I just want to confirm that this is the correct way of handling this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, create the private field in the class

Note you also need to call the init method of the Foo$class module

If you want to see exactly what you need to do, just create a Scala class that extends Foo, compile it, and then use a decompiler (jd-gui) to see how it was generated.

Comment: Thanks. And thanks for the extending the class trick. I did originally look at the scala code in jd-gui, but not with a custom class.